# How many neutrons would it take to boil a gallon of water?

Tags: temperature, neutrons

How many neutrons would it take to boil a gallon of water?

Comment: There is only one kind of neutron, namely, the neutron. Did you mean neutron stars? Or something else?

Comment: Are you looking for [neutron temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_temperature)?  To convert to kelvin use $E=kT$ with the Boltzmann constant $k = \rm 25\,meV / 300\,K$; you can convert to other temperature scales from there.

Comment: Well, there are the frigid ones at 0-20°K, the cold ones at 20-100°K, the cool ones at 100-293°K, the room-temperature ones at 294°K, the warm ones at 295-350°K, the hot ones at 350-2000°K, the roasting ones at 2000-10000°K, and the toastalicious ones at 10000+°K. (Ooops: you asked for Celsius; subtract 273 from the above.)

Comment: You appear to have made no effort at all to solve your own problem.   If you are not willing to try to solve it, why should anyone else do it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One really, really energetic one might do it. But it would need to be very close to the speed of light, and I'm not sure you could capture its energy to boil the water.

Assuming you want to convert the mass of a non-relativistic neutron to energy, it's about 940 MeV per neutron. Boiling a gallon of water (starting at room temperature, 20°C) requires raising the temperature by 80°C. I am assuming you don't mean "boil until it is all evaporated" - if you did, we would have to add the considerable heat of evaporation.

The [heat capacity of a gallon of water](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=heat+capacity+of+US+gallon+of+water) is 15.8 kJ/K, so raising a gallon by 80°C takes 1.3 MJ. Divide this by the energy of a single neutron (940 MeV = $1.5\cdot 10^{-10}$ J) and you get $8.6\cdot 10^{15}$ neutrons.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the water can't cool, then after about 30 minutes, all the neutrons have decayed to protons and electrons, the resultant antineutrinos escape, but an average of around 0.5 MeV per decay will get thermalised in the water (the range of the electrons will be of order 1cm).

As Floris points out, it takes 15.8kJ to heat a gallon of water by 1K, so this takes $2\times 10^{17}$ neutron decays. To raise by 80K, takes 80 times as many.